# 3rd Party badges in Chrome DevTools: Colours

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Was wondering if anyone had insight on the significance of 3rd Party badges in DevTools, and specifically **their colours**? They vary across the board and was curious how this gets decided and why.

Answer (score 0):

Colors are generated based on product names (so they are consistent between reloads). They don't have any special meaning.

From [BadgePool.js](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/product_registry/BadgePool.js?l=177&rcl=97601053cedab95087d4aa1248dd40bf9d9531b9) (where `entryName` could be something like "Google Analytics"):

```js
  static colorForEntryName(entryName) {
    if (!ProductRegistry.BadgePool._colorGenerator) {
      ProductRegistry.BadgePool._colorGenerator =
          new Common.Color.Generator({min: 30, max: 330}, {min: 50, max: 80, count: 3}, 80);
    }
    return ProductRegistry.BadgePool._colorGenerator.colorForID(entryName);
  }
```

And from Common.Color.Generator:

```js
  /**
   * @param {string} id
   * @return {string}
   */
  colorForID(id) {
    var color = this._colors.get(id);
    if (!color) {
      color = this._generateColorForID(id);
      this._colors.set(id, color);
    }
    return color;
  }

  /**
   * @param {string} id
   * @return {string}
   */
  _generateColorForID(id) {
    var hash = String.hashCode(id);
    var h = this._indexToValueInSpace(hash, this._hueSpace);
    var s = this._indexToValueInSpace(hash >> 8, this._satSpace);
    var l = this._indexToValueInSpace(hash >> 16, this._lightnessSpace);
    var a = this._indexToValueInSpace(hash >> 24, this._alphaSpace);
    return `hsla(${h}, ${s}%, ${l}%, ${a})`;
  }
```

Comment: Got it. Wanted to make sure there wasn't any significance. Thx!